# Video inside the frame

Tags: video, video-streaming

I have created the following image change using JavaScript, http://www.mirrortvsolutions.com/web/tv.html what I want to do next is to have a video inside the frame with play and stop button.

When user goes on the page it shows the mirror and then they press play and the video plays and when they press stop it change back to mirror

Can this be possible?

thanks

Ruksana

Bascially what I am after is to have play button and stop button when play is press the video appears inside the frame, and when stop is press it change back to the mirror image

Answer (score 0):

If you upload an image to the box, then make the DIV surrounding the image include the video link, it would work. That's how it's done on that site:

```
enter code here<div id="video_embed_29800" class="video_embed">
<iframe id="big_video_fullplayer29800" width="560" height="330" frameborder="0" data-newsrc="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6RNIjd_ShKc?wmode=transparent&autoplay=1" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/6RNIjd_ShKc?wmode=transparent&autoplay=0" type="text/html">
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
</iframe>
<img id="big_video_fullimage29800" alt="" src="http://www.garancedore.fr/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/tkh1-copy.jpg">
</div>
```

Do you see how they achieved it? Use Firebug to find the CSS for video_embed class on that site.